# How to change value in textbox with JQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on an ajax call that will update the value of a textbox:

```
<div id="PNIncrementDiv" style="position:absolute; left: 730px; top: 15px; width: 350px;" class="">

 <input id="TBIncrementTextBox"  class="textbox" type="text" style="position:absolute; top:25px; left: 75px; width: 60px; height: 40px;" runat="server"  />

</div>
```

My ajax function, which returns an integer, and Is tested to be returning the correct answer is below:

```
getIncrement: function (id) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "<%=Session("BaseUri")%>" + '/handlers/DataEntry/SPC_InspectionInput.ashx',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { method: 'getIncrement', args: { IncrementId: id} },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        Inc_Num = data;
                        $('#TBIncrementTextBox').val(data.toString());//nothing happens!

                    },
                    error: function (a, b, c) {
                        alert(c);
                    }
                });

            }
```

However, when I try to change the value of the textbox, nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is actually being made, and is successful? Check the console as you most likely have some errors which need to be diagnosed andfixed

Comment: The URL starts with " and finishes with ', but i think this is not a problem

Comment: @Gaetano It's two separate strings. The first is delimited with `"`, the second with `'`. It's confusing, but it's valid. I agree it should be changed though. There's no need to append the strings at all as the first value is coming from the server.

Comment: What is output of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  That AJAX request is returning data from a database column.  I have set an alert on the 'data' return value, and the alert returns the correct db value every time.

Comment: it's very strange. Check this JSFIDDLE. https://jsfiddle.net/fgfv7mLg/

Comment: Can you add the data you are returning??

Comment: is this asp.net web forms project?

Comment: The output of console.log(data) is 0.  If there was an error, I have it set to return -1.

Comment: I just noticed your `runat="server"` attribute at the end of the element. That's the problem. If you check the HTML source in your browser you'll see that the `id` has been changed at runtime by ASP.Net. You need to retrieve the element using the `ClientID` property instead - or use a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try targeting the input box using `$('#PNIncrementDiv input').val(data.toString());`
If that works, your ASP.NET script is most likely altering your target input's ID

Answer (score 2):

try to use value method

```
$('#TBIncrementTextBox')[0].value = data.toString()
```

```js
getIncrement: function (id) {
            $.ajax({

                url: "<%=Session("BaseUri")%>" + '/handlers/DataEntry/SPC_InspectionInput.ashx',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { method: 'getIncrement', args: { IncrementId: id} },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    Inc_Num = data;
                    $('#TBIncrementTextBox')[0].value = data.toString();//nothing happens!

                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(c);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: This will result in a syntax error as a jQuery object has no `value` property

Comment: thanks Rory I've just fixed it and tested. But the best would be to get working code to find out if there is anything else wrong

Comment: At least you've fixed the error, but this is now logically identical. If the original didn't work, then there's no reason this would either.